# Group import from Active Directory via LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We're using LDAP to authenticate users against a large Active Directory setup. We want to extract the list of all groups from Active Directory so that we can mirror them in a local database, and map users' AD groups to local groups.

However when we run the ldap query to get a list of all groups, Active Directory limits the maximum results for our search.

What is the best strategy to get this information given the limitations on query result size? Can we use some form of query paging?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language or script are you using ?

Comment: We are using python. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active-Directory support pagging control. You must refer to Microsoft official article : [Searching the Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180879%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) ans especialy [Search Size and Page Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180880%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A [simple paged results query](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2696) can be used to do that. The key would be to ensure that the requested page size does not exceed whatever the maximum results size is for your Active Directory instance.

The ADO wrappers for ADSI, for example, automatically page results, an example of which can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), though obviously that may or may not work for you depending on your technology stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for any GroupPrincipal 
GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

// to get around the 1'000 or so object limit - you need to "go deep" and
// set the page size on the underlying DirectorySearcher to e.g. 500
(searcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher).PageSize = 500;

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

You can specify any of the properties on the `GroupPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.